# Can I create a node, assign a language and provide it a menu link with Drush?

Tags: drush

Just that. Can I create a node, assign a language and provide it  a menu link with Drush?

Let say, I want to create a node:

- of the **basic** content type
- with **title** set to "my title"
- set to **es** language
- and provide it  a menu link in the **Main menu**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box. See this [prior related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68490/can-i-create-nodes-through-drush-for-particular-content-type), all of these examples are created through the Devel 'generate content' library but they assume generic (ex. lipsum) content. For a custom build like you are asking with a specific title, you're best bet is going to be to create a [custom Drush plugin](http://drush.ws/docs/commands.html) using node_save to [programmatically create a node](https://drupal.org/node/889058) with the values you want.